# How can I define a function of type Integral a => a?

Tags: haskell

We've just started learning Haskell at uni, and in one of my homework problems, we have to define a function for this type signature:

```
f1 :: Integral a => a
```

To be honest, I'm still trying to understand a bunch of basics about Haskell, but I know that with `Integral`, you can do `mod` and `div`, plus the ones you can do with `Num`, `+`, `-` and `*`.

So I could write

```
f1 :: Integral a=> a -> a
f1 k = k `mod` k
```

And it would work. But with

```
f1 :: Integral a => a
```

There seems to be no output.

How can I write something with this that doesn't give an error when interpreted?

Comment: You got it backwards! It has an output, but no *input*.

Comment: Note that `Integral a => a` is *not* a function type. Haskell doesn't have functions of zero arguments.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're right that `Integral` doesn't have anything of that shape. But `Integral` is also a [lot of other things](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.15.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#t:Integral), and if we trace the hierarchy up, we see that every `Integral` is a `Num`, and every `Num` has

```
fromInteger :: Num a => Integer -> a
```

So, for your function, we could write

```
f1 :: Integral a => a
f1 = fromInteger 0
```

or

```
f1 :: Integral a => a
f1 = fromInteger 42
```

or, frankly, pick your favorite number.

Also, because of Haskell magic, the *literal* number `42` is actually `fromInteger 42` (the literal `42`, in Haskell, has type `Num a => a`. So this function will suffice as well.

```
f1 :: Integral a => a
f1 = 42
```